# Block Adult Websites

Tags: browser, internet, parental-control, content-filter

Is it possible to block all porn, chat sites, and adult content web pages on a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2? And is it possible to hide the fact that they are being blocked?

Comment: OpenDNS free service may also work.

Comment: How do you want to hide the fact that they're blocked without blocking them... by blocking them. (And most likely presenting some error or blocking page instead), you're showing that they're blocked...

Comment: I'm facing an issue like this with my 11 years old brother. I can't figure out a solution that won't be wipe out by factory reset, unistaling the apps, or simply desactivate it. Blocking 100% is not an issue even 50% will be enought. But openDns need to be set on every wifi they have access. Application block can be desactivate in few click. it's perhaps because m still a bit choked.

Answer (score 14):

### Using only your Android:

[Kaspersky's Parental Control software](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaspersky.pctrl) does exactly as the title says.

Mind you, it's still in beta, but I did install it and tried it out, and it seems to do it's job of blocking websites as well as applications.

By the way, Kaspersky's not the only app out on the store that you can use, but I chose it due to its reputation. It's after all an application that is going to monitor the network traffic and if it's just any other app, it could steal your credit card numbers maybe. Who knows.

PS: As far as I know, this application cannot be hidden, unless of course you installed a launcher like Smart Launcher. Even then, there is an option for you to show the hidden applications, so it's not going to do much good.

### If the phone/tablet is accessing the internet through the Wifi alone:

In this case, you can setup your router settings so that it blocks certain sites etc. It won't be too hard to find the settings; just enter this URL in your browser - 192.168.1.1 - and you should get an interface to login to the router.

For more info, I suggest you did a search on Google on how to block sites through your router.

### Advanced Option

I'm not very sure about this method but it should work.

- Get a server setup to act as a proxy.
- Setup a program on the machine so that it'll be able to monitor and restrict access to a selected number of websites.
- Route the phone through the proxy server... and it should do the job.

PS: I welcome comments from anyone who knows if this method is really workable.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to block **all** such sites.  That would either require a 100% effective blacklist, which would be impossible to maintain, or a 100% effective detection mechanism, which would basically be an artificial intelligence capable of making human-like judgements.

You can get all kinds of parental controls and blockers on the Play store, but there won't be anything 100% effective.  They may block the most common sites by domain, or block based on keywords (which will block a lot of legitimate sites as well), but none will block ass.

What might be more effective would be a whitelist, depending on how the phone is used.  A firewall whitelist would limit the phone to only being able to access a predefined list of sites (eg, youtube, facebook, etc.)

Comment: +1 - There's not, and likely never will be a 100% solution to this.....if it can be blocked, it can be worked around, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted you could use [ad-away](http://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/adaway/) to add your custom list of forbidden hosts.

It writes the hosts file to put lines like this:

```
website_to_block 127.0.0.1
```

So a request in your browser to the "website_to_block" will be displayed as "This website is not avalaible"

Comment: The safest way to get a copy of ad-away is to install [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) and use that to obtain it.  Or you can download the [ad away APK](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=away&fdid=org.adaway) directly from F-Droid, too.  "On this site you’ll find a repository of FOSS apps, along with an Android client to perform installations and updates, and news, reviews and other features covering all things Android and software-freedom related. F-Droid is a non-profit organisation registered in England (no. 8420676)."