# How to block websites on Android (for free) without root?

Tags: content-filter

I want to block websites on my HTC phone. 
It seems as though ES File Explorer needs the phone to be rooted to use this method, which I don't want to do. (I don't have any folders when I click through 'Local'-'Device' at all, which is where you're supposed to find 'etc' so I can't go any further anyway)
Trend Mirco is far too expensive for the premium version which lets you block any site name (given I'm trying to block sites where I can spend money!)
Firefox Add Ons don't seem to work on the mobile version, they will download, but I have no way of opening them.
Apps all seem to be about blocking adult content on kid's phones, which isn't the issue here. 
On the desktop computer I've used Leechblock for Firefox, and BlockSite for Chrome. 
Any other ideas that don't cost anything or require a rooted device?

Comment: I'm not sure if anything here would help you: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53833/1465