# Block top level domains in my device

Tags: browser, internet, dns, private-dns

In my pursuit to block porn, I installed many web filtering options. Currently, I am using Open Dns free version and Blockerhero for blocking specific domains and apps. However my issue is that sometimes these blocked websites popup with new names. For instance:

> 1filmy4wap.biz

> https://tode793.com/selinte-tuition-class-2022-e01-02-yessma-seris-720p-480p-webhd-x264/

These post erotic content and are replica of each other. How many domains can I block, it seems almost impossible. Is there any solution anyone can offer?

Like anything with which I can block domains more easily. Or block those services which have pirated content like streamsb.

Comment: Related: [How to block access to a website?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16485/44325), [Block Adult Websites](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53833/44325)

Comment: The only solution is to have someone (e.g. a community) that maintains the block lists so that new domains are not blocked immediately but in short time.